# Choosing Error Message on AJAX Call

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm new to using AJAX (but decently experienced in jQuery and PHP) and am wondering if I can have several different error messages on one AJAX call depending on what occurs.

Here is my AJAX function. I'm basically checking the username and e-mail that are used on an HTML form on the page. I'm sending those values to be checked in the database, and if they exists, I need to display an appropriate error message. I need two different messages though. One to say 'That username already exists. Please try again.' and one for e-mail.:

```
var username = $('input[name="username"]').val();
var email = $('input[type="email"]').val();

var myData =
'username='+ username +
'&email='+ email;

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST', // HTTP method POST or GET
    url: 'signup_ajax.php', //Where to make Ajax calls
    dataType:'text', // Data type, HTML, json etc.
    data:myData, //post variables
    success:function(response){
        $('#register_form').submit();
    },
    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
        alert('There was an error.');
    }
});
```

I'm assuming these error messages would come on a 'successful' AJAX call because it's not that the call wouldn't connect to the database, it just wouldn't produce results. I'm figuring there is a way to send data back to the form page from the AJAX PHP page? I was thinking of setting an error message variable to a certain value on the PHP page and then trying to send it back to the Javascript page to be displayed. Is that possible to do? I know I can do these through two separate AJAX calls but I'm just trying to see if it's possible to streamline it into one function. Thanks!

Comment: If you're asking if you can send a new response through the same connection that the ajax that raised an error was using, by the time _error_ is called, that connection has already been closed (and _JavaScript_ would not have access to it anyway). The way connections happen on the web is **0.** client opens connection. **1.** client sends request headers. **2.** server sends response headers. **3.** server sends response body (if any). **4.** connection is closed. The client sending more data after step 1 would be very peculiar.

Comment: that would be the reply from the server, you check there and it reply's back the result, if it was "password" or "email" or "valid" to signal your response, the first two will be types of errors, and the other one "valid" is when it succeeds, all is handled inside success call. or you could use numbers to minimize data size.

Comment: @PaulS. is right. when you are at the function error, the connection is already closed. but i guess it's this way by design, what if in the error function you try to make another request goes wrong and loop in the same function? the connection will never close and that's bad

Comment: @PaulS., I don't think I'm necessarily referring to the AJAX error function. Essentially what I'm doing is querying the database and was to check for the number of rows that contains the certain email or username. If the number rows is greater than zero (meaning it already exists in the database), I want a message to say 'This username already exists.' So in essence, I suppose it would be like an if statement in the 'success' function of the AJAX call since it'll successfully be executing a query. Am I making sense? Maybe I'm approaching the issue wrong?

Comment: make json response and put your error messages in that. then check in 'success' function if your error messages are null or not.